# "Run until complete" loop does not end after function is complete?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have been working on a Discord bot that pulls information from Ubisoft's Rainbow Six Siege stats API. I am new to coding and I know it's a bit of a bodge, but to retrieve stats I am using some sample code I found in the [API's documentation](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/rainbowsixsiege-python-api/latest/rainbowsixsiege-python-api.pdf):

```
    @types.coroutine
def run():
    auth = api.Auth("my_email", "my_password")
    player = yield from auth.get_player(username, api.Platforms.UPLAY)
    operator = yield from player.get_operator(oprtr)
    print(operator.kills)
    global result
    result = (operator.kills)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(run())

print (result)
```

I placed this inside of a command function I created:

```
@client.command()
async def wins(ctx, username, oprtr):
    print (username, oprtr)
```

Which, together, gives the code below, which I have annotated to show how the loop doesn't end. On its own (without being inside a command), the @types.coroutine works fine, it is just when it is inside of @client.command() that the loop doesn't end.

```
@client.command()
async def wins(ctx, username, oprtr):
    print (username, oprtr)

    @types.coroutine
    def run():
        auth = api.Auth("my_email", "my_password")
        player = yield from auth.get_player(username, api.Platforms.UPLAY)
        operator = yield from player.get_operator(oprtr)
        print(operator.kills)     #this value prints, so the function definitely works.
        global result
        result = (operator.kills)

    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(run()) #this is the loop which seems to never end,
                                                       #and blocks anything from progressing

    print (result)           #these two outputs do not send, which tells me that everything is being
    await ctx.send("Hello")  #blocked by the loop
```

As I said, I'm a fairly new and pretty rubbish coder so I appreciate any help, this has been bugging me all day! If you need any more information I will do my best to give you it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a ruin until complete loop, maybe try looping until a certain variable is true or false.

```
notdone = true
while notdone == true:
    #do whatever in here and when you want it to finish, just set notdone to false.
```